# Previous Blackberry Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

How can i install previous blackberry plugin in eclipse,which is             1.5.2.201204302029

[image]

but after installing from url
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java

and other
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/downloads/eclipseplugin/beta/

i get version 2.0.0.201207181003 but i want its previous version which is 1.5.2.201204302029
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seem you need to select the old version manually.
just try: window->preferences->java->installed jres, you see, they all sleep there, select what you want.

Comment: it is java runtime their nor blackberry plugin.